# Application Insights - Autoscale has not been able to read monitoring data for resource

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-application-insights

I've working an application and I use WorkerRole with multiple instance ( Autoscale options ). Couple of days ago the AI ( Application Insights ) starts sending emails about the monitoring data not available.

Autoscale has not been able to read monitoring data for resource 'Application' since 'Date' UTC. The capacity will be adjusted when Autoscale successfully reads monitoring data for your resource.

After couple of hour I get notification about "Autoscale is now able to read metrics for resource". 
This thing usually happen beetween 1 - 3 AM.

Any ideas what cause this issue?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think Autoscale uses Application Insights data. It uses standard metrics collected by WAD agent. There is [an explanation](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/bc2048c4-8d49-4c54-b150-f263808c4b7a/notification-could-not-automatically-scale-xxx-because-monitoring-data-was-not-found?forum=windowsazuremanagement) that may be applicable for your case:

> As you know Autoscale requires monitoring data to be collected from your VM/role instances in order to scale. However, there can be times when there is not any monitoring data available. Two common causes of this are a problem inside the role instance that prevents it from writing out data (e.g. it is recycling), or, throttling or a network issue on the storage accounts that contain your monitoring data. If either of these happen then autoscale will (temporality) be unable to calculate how many instances you should have. As soon as the roles or storage accounts are healthy again, autoscale will automatically resume as it was before. There is not explicit action that you or support can take to bring autoscale back.

You may want to check the health of your roles and/or logs from the storage account. Also you may choose to enable [WAD 2 AI](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-cloudservices/#azure-diagnostics) to see WAD data in AI to diagnose why metrics may not be available in the nights